# Get routes of Rails app without running rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

My understand of rake routes is that it bootstraps the Rails application and then pulls the routes from it. If I want to simply look at the text (no loading of a rails application) and be able to output something similar to what rake routes outputs, how would I do it? I know rake routes actually runs Ruby code and I am worried about doing so as I do not trust these applications.

I am weary to load the Rails application as I do not trust these Rails applications, but if there is a way to sandbox the running of rake routes or some related method, I would be open to that as well.

Comment: Put the app into a Vagrant sandbox and run it there: http://www.vagrantup.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex routes file with lots of engines you'd probably be better off using Vagrant to run the app in a sandbox. If it's simple though, this method might work for you.

Rails will generate routes from routes.rb without the underlying application. Create a new dummy app making sure you match the rails version to the version of the app you want to inspect.

```
> rails new dummy_app
  …

> cd dummy_app
> cp /path/to/untrusted/app/config/routes.rb ./config/
```

Edit the app name at the top of the route file to match the name of the dummy app, in this case it would be `DummyApp.Application.routes.draw do`. Then run

```
> rake routes
```

Some caveats: If there are any engines or gem speficic routes in there you'll need to add those to the Gemfile or comment out those routes. For example, if the pap uses active_admin you'll need to add that to the gemfile as well as generate the AdminUser class. And then you'll want to recopy over the routes files as the generator adds lines to the routes file. If you run into issues with uninitialized contents you may need an initializer to require certain classes. For example, if you mount Resque::Server, you need an initializer with these two lines:

```
# config/initializers/dummy_init.rb
require 'resque'
require 'resque/server'
```